# How can I configure which .tex should be compiled when clicking on 'quick build' in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker

I have a document that comprises a few .tex files: `main.tex` and a few `chapX.tex`. When I edit chapX.tex in [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), I would like that clicking on 'quick build' compiles `main.tex` and not chapX.tex (which fails since this is not the main document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing `main.tex` you should click on:

[image]